# JavaFX show ContextMenu below cursor

Tags: javafx, contextmenu, javafx-8

I have a TextField where the user can type. I would like to show a ContextMenu below cursor when the user hit Ctrl+Space key combination.

```
codeArea.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            if( event.getCode().equals( KeyCode.SPACE ) && event.isControlDown() ) {
                int cursorX = ?;
                int cursorY = ?;
                cm.show(codeArea, x, y);
            } else {
                cm.hide();
            }
});
```

How I get the cursor current position? I must give it's (screen) XY coords to the show() function.

I'd like use it for auto completion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add a MouseListener and save the last position in a Variable :)

You might wanna use getScreenX() and getScreenY() not sure of the difference at the moment.

```
codeArea.setOnMouseMoved(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
  @Override public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
      this.cursorX = event.getX();
      this.cursorY = event.getY();
  }
});
```